# Does missing the first leg of an ARNK (open-jaw) reservation automatically cancel the remainder of the itinerary?

Tags: regulations, bookings, open-jaw

Normally, when not flying a leg in your reservation, the airlines will [cancel the rest of the reservation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/not-flying-the-first-leg-of-the-journey-company-cancels-the-second-leg-ticket). Does the same rule apply for open-jaw reservations? I can't seem to find any official reference for this.

Comment: Why would it be any different?

Comment: @Gagravarr ARNK can be so flexible, sometimes multiple ARNKS in the middle of one reservation in a very long period which makes the possibility of losing one leg is much more than a normal reservation.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here. What is ARNK?

Comment: @Bernhard it is open-jaw.. the more technical term for that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same airline the whole way through and/or all sectors are on the one ticket, it will be counted as a 'no-show', and your onward flights will most likely be cancelled. If it's a separate airline and a separate ticket, then the no-show prior to the ARNK shouldn't impact your onward travel.